# neo4j - how to show more than two path for a single node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

when b have two relations:

> match (a)<--(b)--->(c)
>
> return a,b,c

but what if b have more than 2 relation :

> match (a)<--(b)--->(c) (b)--->(d)
>
> return a,b,c,d

this gives and error.

how do i perform this relation

[image: See screen Shot Here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have some typos in your `match` statement:

```
match (a)<--(b)--->(c) (b)--->(d)
```

First: The arrow between `(b)` and `(c)` has too many dashes (as does the one between `(b)` and `(d)`)
Second: You have two match paths, and they need to be separated by comma.

So... try:

```
match (a)<--(b)-->(c), (b)-->(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David's answer, If you want to get all nodes related to `(b)` you can use something like this:

```
match (b)-[r*n]-(p) return b, p;
```

where `r` is your relationship name and `n` is the relationship depth, which I assume is `1` in your case.